# customization for nested routes in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url-routing, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using nested routes in my application (rails 3.2) as follows:

```
resources :networks do
  resources :groups
end
```

The route for groups show page is as follows

```
network_group GET    /networks/:network_id/groups/:id(.:format)
```

How can I change the parameters to :network_name and :group_name respectively? Also, I would like to rename the route to group_path (instead of network_group_path ). I would like these changes reflected for all the routes without having to use 'match' for the individual routes.

Is it possible to have something like group_path(@network, @group) return '/networks/global/groups/all', where 'global' and 'all' are both 'name' attribute for the respective models. (by default I get the id's in the url)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do that by adding a to_param method in our model

http://railscasts.com/episodes/63-model-name-in-url

In your network and group model, add a #to_param method that returns what you want in the URL (network_name, group_name).

Or else you can use friendly_id gem which gives pretty urls.

Answer (score 0):

You can use friendly_id gem. https://github.com/norman/friendly_id